# Pinescript V5: Controlling Z-Index of line.new(), plotting newer lines below older lines

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I understand you can use `explicit_plot_zorder = true` within an indicator to set the Z-Index of hlines, plots etc. based on code position.

My indicator uses the line.new() function to create rays, and I need to control the Z-Index of these somehow, so newer lines are layered BELOW older lines.

Is this possible in any way?

To give some context, this script is to draw horizontal rays for weekly/monthly/quarterly/yearly OHL, as below.

I want to ensure that Yearly lines (no matter when they originate) are always layered on top of quarterly, and quarterly always over monthly etc.

Currently, it is achieved by duplicating the indicator 4 times, keeping yearly at top of the list and weekly at the bottom.

[image: tradingview image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution - use hline instead of line.new()

Comment: I am drawing rays, opposed to horizontal lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of line data object that you only draw on the last bar (or whatever applies to your strategy). Depending on how often and how many lines you have this may not be as performant but the only solution I can think of. Also keep in mind the drawable lines limit (eg. 500 for premium)

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", "t", true)

type LineData
    int x1
    float y1
    int x2
    float y2

var lineDataArray = array.new<LineData>()
var lines = array.new<line>()

if bar_index % 100 == 0
    array.unshift(lineDataArray, LineData.new(time, high, time + 1440*60000, high))

if barstate.islast // or what is applicable for you each new day? new week?
    for l in lines
        line.delete(l)
    for ld in lineDataArray
        newLine = line.new(ld.x1, ld.y1, ld.x2, ld.y2, xloc = xloc.bar_time)
        array.push(lines, newLine)
```